# Permanent Phonegap Local Storage

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Phonegap to create Android application. I`m using Local Storage to save score and when I close app Local Storage gets deleted.  How I can store data permanently?

I`m using this code to write data:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("DataToStore", "0");
```

Comment: here's the Phonegap documentation on [device storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html)

Comment: localStorage isn't deleted on my apps. Can you give more details? android version, cordova version, etc

Comment: Android Versions: 2.3.6 and 4.2.2. Phonegap Version: 5.1.1. Compiled with Android SDK 10.